# How can I use Swift to call an objective-C method that expects an argument of type (int *)?

Tags: objective-c, swift

An existing objective-C method has the following signature:

```
-(BOOL)barcodeSetScanBeep:(BOOL)enabled volume:(int)volume beepData:(int *)data length:(int)length error:(NSError **)error;
```

Note that `beepData:` expects (int *).

This method can be used from objective-C by passing in a C array:

```
int beepData[] = {1200,100};
```

How can I call the same method from Swift? My best attempt, `let beepData: [Int] = [1200, 100]`, doesn't compile.

Comment: I was just about to ask (and hopefully answer after a bit of research) this question. ;)

Comment: Gah, just found the answer and somebody has beaten be to it.

Comment: there s something relevant in swift oc interaction doc from Apple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int` is a C 32-bit integer and mapped to Swift as `Int32`.

A `int *` parameter is mapped to Swift as `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>`,
and you can pass a *variable* array as "inout parameter" with `&`.

So it should roughly look like this:

```
var beepData : [ Int32 ] = [ 1200, 100 ]
var error : NSError?
if !DTDevices.sharedDevice().barcodeSetScanBeep(true, volume: Int32(100),
                beepData: &beepData, length: Int32(beepData.count),
                error: &error) {
    println(error!)
}
```

Swift defines also a type alias

```
/// The C 'int' type.
typealias CInt = Int32
```

so you could replace `Int32` by `CInt` in above code if you want to emphasize that
you are working with C integers.

For more information, see ["Interacting with C APIs"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html) in the ["Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/) documentation.

Comment: I was just about to say this, yeah, & makes it an inout param for use in pointer parameters.

Comment: What's the reason to convert the other `int` values to `Int32`, out of interest?

Comment: @BenPackard: The `length` parameter is a `int` which is `Int32` in Swift. On the other hand, `beepData.count` is an `Int`. Swift does not implicitly convert types.

Comment: I had to use `Int32(beepData.count * sizeof(Int32))` for length, based on your own answer to another question 25714086 - does that seem right?

Comment: @BenPackard: That depends on how the length is interpreted: As the number of *integers* or as the number of *bytes*. I don't know the barcodeSetScanBeep  function, so I assumed the former. For the number of bytes, your formula is correct.