# How do I declare a C array in Swift?

Tags: c, arrays, swift

In OC:

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    int items[3];
}
```

In Swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // ???...
}
```

---

And I do this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var fuItems: [Int32] = []
}
```

But below function return a error:

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef)renderPixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBuffer withFrameId:(int)frameid items:(int*)items itemCount:(int)itemCount flipx:(BOOL)flip;
```

Error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[Int32]' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>!'
```

Could you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Your declaration is correct (except you passed from `int` to `Int32`, but that's a minor change). The issue is that in `items:(int*)items`, there is a extra `*`. In Objective-C, we would often do `&items`, but in Swift you have to use `UnsafeMutablePointer`. There are questions on SO about using `UnsafeMutablePointer`. Did you check them?

Comment: @Larme Yes you are right, I'm so agree with you. But I take a look at Demo code: `[[FURenderer shareRenderer] renderPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer withFrameId:frameID items:items itemCount:3 flipx:YES];`(OC), he just put`items` here, not `&items` and it runs ok?

Comment: if expected argument type is 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>!', then you have to pass &fuItems as the parameter of the function.

Comment: Expected argument type is `int *` - C int array...

Comment: @Larme: The C `int` type is a 32-bit integer on all Apple platforms, the corresponding Swift type is `Int32`.

Comment: @Leo: In C, an array "automatically" becomes a pointer when passed to a function. In Swift, you have to pass `&fuItems`. – Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103817/how-can-i-use-swift-to-call-an-objective-c-method-that-expects-an-argument-of-ty, which might qualify as a duplicate.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you `&items` works for me :)